# Strange problem with Photoshop font

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

I have very strange problem with Photoshop CS4 and CS5 on Windows XP and Windows 7.

I've Installed all necessery fonts for template that I receive from graphic designer.
This fonts was Sansation and Sansation Light.

In Windows all fonts are installed sucessfully. I see the fonts in photoshop but when I try to open the templace (psd file) it tells me that some fonts missing.

With text tool I select the text element and photohop tells me:

```
"the following fonts are missing for text layer
 Sansation
 warning that a substitution will occur"
```

After this the font is marked as [Sansation] (with brackets). I know that's means something wrong with that font. But when I searching for the font on the photoshop font list there is a font named "Sansation" and "Sansation Light" and at the end of font list is again [Sansation] with brackets.

What is funny is that when I create new psd file then I can use "Sansation" font without any problems.

When I open the template I can use this font too but when I select text elements with "text tool" then the above message appears. It seems to me that Photoshop in this particular moment didn't see this font.

I know that Graphic Designer created this template with CS5 version of Photoshop.
What I want is open this template without any warnings.

I installed fonts in: Windows\Fonts and in Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Fonts
but the situation is the same.

Can somebody give me some advice what is wrong?

**UPDATE INFORMATION**

First of all thank you very much for Your comments. I ask my Graphic Designer to send me the same versions of font. He downloaded from internet the newest version of Sansation font and prepare for me again the same template but with the newest fonts. After that he send me the template and the newest version of the font. After that everything works fine.

It seems to me that we both have diffrent font versions at the begining. Thanku You very much for Your sugestions in comments.

Comment: Did you try replacing all the instances of the font in the template with your copy of the font and saving it with a new name? Then open your version and see if it works. If so, use yours and toss the other one.

Comment: I understand if it was for example 3 text elements but the number of text elements is much higher and doing it by hand is a lot of work for me. What is strange that when [Sansation] fonts appear with braces in the font list the icon text to it is Open Type. The font "Sansation" that I installed is True Type. Does it make any diffrence for Photoshop to recognize that font exists?

Comment: OH yes. TrueType vs. OpenType is your problem. Happens all across the Adobe Suite.

Comment: So I need to convert this font *.ttf files to *.otf with some kind of converter and install it into the windows? What software can make such conversion?

Comment: Note that, for the future, if you create a *shortcut* to the windows/fonts folder in the prog/common/adobe/fonts folder you don't need to double install fonts in both places: anything in the windows/fonts folder will be detected by PS.

Comment: also, truetype can be shown with an "O" icon. Check for yourself: go to windows/fonts, right click the name/font style (etc) row of column headers, check (enable) "font filenames", find TTF fonts, then check PS list.

Comment: And lastly, Sansation appears to be freeware. Try getting the fonts from the designer. (S)He may have a different revision of the font file than you have.

Comment: Right on, Horatio. Getting the same fonts is *by far* the best solution to this issue.

Comment: @Lauren, Horatio - TrueType and OpenType are not mutually exclusive. OpenType fonts may store glyph outlines in either TrueType (.TTF) or PostScript (.OTF) format. The "O" icon is used for the former; the TTF extension does not in itself distinguish between a TrueType font or a newer TrueType-flavoured OpenType font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been hashed out in the comments, the problem is that your designer used OTF fonts and you have installed TTF versions.

You might think that the simple handling would be to just convert your TTF to OTF using one of the conversion utilities out there, and it *might* work out okay in this one case, but it is a **very bad practice** -- one you should avoid except when there is no alternative. Here's why:

The designer has laid things out using a specific version (revision) of two fonts. You have no way of knowing whether the TTF version you have is the same, under the hood, as the designer's OTF. There may be subtle differences in kerning tables and individual character widths or side bearings that change how the text "sets." If you use a font file that is a different revision level from the one used by the designer, *the text will almost certainly reflow*, altering (and possibly wrecking) the carefully crafted design. This problem is not restricted to Photoshop; it applies anywhere you have text in a layout application.

So the more general, and much safer approaches when you get files from a designer are either:

- Get the exact same fonts and install them on your system, or
- Require the designer to outline (or, in the case of Photoshop, rasterize) all type before sending you the file.

Rasterizing is not an option if the type is small (<=18 pt for sans serif, <=24 pt for serif) and you intend to go to print with the artwork, so for purposes of working with Photoshop the recommendation is always to install the correct fonts.

This is a **very important** general principle in working with type. Many a design has been wrecked because the file went to a prepress department that used a slightly different version of the fonts used by the designer. That kind of problem can be very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert your font from ttf to otf you can use some Font converter Site like: http://onlinefontconverter.com

Answer (score 0):

If you have an OTF version of the font, ensure the .otf files are installed on BOTH systems. .otf fonts are universal.